# File Management over Network for Multiple Users

Tags: file-management, images, network-administration

As our team grows, we're finding it harder and harder to organize our files, mainly images. Is there a software that will index files on network drives once and have it available to multiple users?

Currently, we're using just Windows Explorer and searches take a while, since each computer has to do their own indexing, I believe. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Everything we have is Windows. The files are stored on remote servers. Network drives are mapped on each workstation so everyone has access to the same files and folders

Comment: It might still be relevant on what system the files are stored. The first solution coming to my mind is having the "organizing/indexing tool" running there as a kind of service the local machines connect to, so index generation and search interface are provided from *there* instead from the local machines. A central index would be a much better (and especially much faster) approach then having each client maintaining its own via a network connection. So physical location has *much* to do with the software, but "mail" has not.

Comment: You might consider git-annex, although it's still in beta on Windows